# Regex: If a backslash occurs dont accept any characters after \

Tags: regex

I have tried various versions of regex but I can't seem to get a version that satisfies my requirements:

1. a string is entered without a backslash, it is matched
2. A string with a backslash is entered, reject everything after the backslash

I have tired:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9/._-]*[(?:\\)]
```

However, it reject's the string after the backslash only when a backslash is in the string. I want that if a string is without backslash it should match

Comment: So basically match everything up to the first backslash? That's trivially solved with `[^\\]*`.

Comment: Thanks that really helped. Tried '[a-zA-Z0-9/._-]*[^\\]*' (since there are some characters i dont want to allow in my string) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(?m)^(?:(?!\\)[-.\w\/ ])*(?:(?=\\)|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P074q8/10)

**Edited** for some reason

Comment: I edited above regex for some reason, please try it again.Thank you:-)

Comment: Thanks !! Aran has a simper solution that worked. yours works as well.